# How to remove Empty Rows from a list in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
apple
mango
banana

tea

coffee
```

Can someone please suggest a python code to remove the empty rows in this case after banana/tea/coffee so the actual result should be as below without any empty rows in between and after the end of lists

```
apple
mango
banana
tea
coffee
```

Comment: You've shown some rows with text, but what is the real data structure?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to filter out empty strings from a list of strings or do you want to skip blank lines when you parse a file?

Comment: i pread a file and done strip and split and got a desire list but with empty rows which i don't want

with open(r'C:\Users\test2.txt','r') as my_file:
    
    my_list = my_file.readlines()
 
for line in my_list:
    extracted_one = line.strip().split(' ') [0] 
    print(extracted_one)


Output is below list with empty rows, how can this blank rows after banan/tea/coffee rows be removed #

apple
mango
banana

tea

coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have forgot to check the spaces after last string in the file. After i remove the spaces and bringing the curser just in parallel to the last string, this solves the problem. thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your list is actually a python list like your title suggests, you can just use filter.

i.e.

```
>>> test_list = ['apple','mango','banana','','tea','','coffee']
>>> test_list = list(filter(None,test_list))
>>> test_list
['apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'tea', 'coffee']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use list comprehension:

```
>>> test_list = ['apple','mango','banana','','tea','','coffee']
>>> test_list = [item for item in test_list if item]
>>> test_list
>>> ['apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'tea', 'coffee']
```

Answer (score 0):

**LIST**

```
list = ["apple", "mango", "banana", "", "tea", "", "coffee"]
while "" in list:
    del list[list.index("")]
print(list)
```

Output:

```
["apple", "mango", "banana", "tea", "coffee"]
```

Comment: i have tested using this code but the last there are still three empty row lines which is still not going away.

Comment: @PSK, I run the code, but I haven't the same problem. Show me an example, please.

Comment: added below codes:
=
    while " " in extracted_one:
        del extracted_one[extracted_one.index(" ")]
    print(extracted_one)

and output below, three blank empty rows still after coffee
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/UsersXXXXX
apple
mango
banana
tea
coffee



>>>

Comment: There's a difference beteween `" "` and `""`.

Comment: if i use without space "" than the output splits the string into characters